# Newsfeed-style appearance of blocks/elements in beamer

Tags: beamer, overlays

I was writing a talk and I had a long example where it would have been useful to look at the most recent few steps.

Some solution that I was not completely happy with was to have the most recent block appear from the bottom, and the rest gets pushed to the top.

I considered doing a "newsfeed"-style overlay where "new blocks" would appear on top. Kind of like a Facebook and Twitter feed. I have working code here:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\only<3->{
\begin{block}{March 8}
    Happy International Women's Day!
\end{block}
}
\only<2->{
\only<3->{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.5}}
\begin{block}{February 14}
    Happy Valentines!
\end{block}
}
\only<1->{
\only<2->{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.5}}
\begin{block}{January 1}
    Happy New Year!
\end{block}
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

One gripe I have of this is I have to manually type in the overlay numbers.

Might there be a way to make this happen? An answer in which "New Year" comes first in the code will also be appreciated.